# Display php result in an HTML table with specific format

Tags: php, arrays, loops, html-table

Basically this is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (            
            [mainProdName] => CellPhone           
            [mainproductname] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (   
                            [subProdName] => TG8                           
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (  
                            [subProdName] => TG5                          
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mainProdName] => LapTop
            [mainproductname] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (   
                            [subProdName] => TD9                          
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (                           
                            [subProdName] => TD7                            
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        ( 
            [mainProdName] => Corn            
            [mainproductname] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (                           
                            [subProdName] => SWEET CORN                            
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

I am trying to display this result in an HTML table

```
<table><tr>
    ?>
        for($j=0;$j<count($res);$j++)
        {
            ?><td>$res[$i].mainProdName}</td><?php
            for($k=0;$k<count($res[$i].mainproductname);$k++)
            {
                ?><td>$res[$i].mainproductname[$k].subProdName}</td><?php
            }
        }
    <?php
</tr></table>
```

For which i'm getting this.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
CellPhone | TG8 | TG5 | LapTop | TD9 | TD7 | Corn | SWEET CORN  
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically i need to display the result in this format

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
       CellPhone       |        LapTop          |       Corn
-----------------------|------------------------|------------------
   TG8     |    TG5    |    TD9    |     TD7    |    SWEET CORN  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For every main product, respective subproduct list should be displayed below in a separate row.

Comment: this is just a simple html mark-up question imho.

Comment: MATAR please check the answer below and check which one is correct for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$first_tr = $second_tr = "<tr>";

foreach($array as $result) {

    // Print the first columns of first row with colspan
    $first_tr .= "<td colspan='" . count($result['mainproductname']) . "'>" . $result['mainProdName'] . "</td>";

    // Loop through the sub-products and print them
    foreach($result['mainproductname'] as $name) {
        $second_tr .= "<td>" . $name['subProdName'] . "</td>";
    }

}

echo $first_tr . "</tr>" . $second_tr . "</tr>";
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/520099)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($res);$i++){ ?>
        <th><?php echo $res[$i].mainProdName;?></th>
    <?php } ?>    
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php for($i=0;$i<count($res);$i++){ ?>
 <tr>
    <?php for($j=0;$j<count($res);$j++){ ?>
    <td><?php echo $res[$i]["mainproductname"]['subProdName'][$j]; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$html ="<table border='1'>";
$html.="<tr>";
$innerhtml="<tr>";
foreach($arr as $key=>$valArr){

    $html.="<td>".$valArr['mainProdName']."</td>";
    if(count($valArr['mainproductname'])){
        $subValArr =array();
        foreach($valArr['mainproductname'] as $subKey => $subVals){
            $subValArr[] = $subVals['subProdName'];

        }
        $subArrString = implode("|", $subValArr);
        $innerhtml.="<td>".$subArrString."</td>" ;
    }


}
$innerhtml.="</tr>";
$html.=$innerhtml;
$html.="</tr>";
$html.="</table>";
echo $html;
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i m using this format to show php result in html table format

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("aggregate",$con);
$q=mysql_query("SELECT ASCII('A');");
echo "<h2>ASCII Function</h2>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><th> ASCII Function</th></tr>";


while($qq=mysql_fetch_row($q)){

    echo "<tr><td> ".$qq[0]. "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in anyways.